# Buttons get longer when pressed if using AJAX

Tags: 7, ajax, theming

I'm using Ajax Commerce Cart Cart with a custom Drupal 7 theme that I made with Artisteer, but the issue does not seem to just be related to the one module. Whenever AJAX is attached to a button, when the button is click it pretty much doubles in width while the AJAX process is taking place and then returns to it's original size.

I wasn't sure what code or information you'd need so please do ask if you need me to upload anything or provide further details. Does anyone know of any solutions to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's the trobber, you know the little .gif image showing an ajax loading.

You can fix it via css, but to find out the class/id to edit, i had to break the ajax and force it to never complete the load, so i had time to inspect the markup with firebug.

check this discussion:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1059674

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I seem to be going along the right lines now - I've found that the button has the extra class of `ajax-processed` but now I'm stuck as I can't find that in my `style.css`, what do I do now?

Comment: Never mind, I found the following css code online which did the trick when I added to my theme's style.css - `.ajax-progress-throbber {
  display: none;
}`. So thanks again, your answer lead me to solving the problem.